# Где найти Пайтон 3.7.2 версии для 64-разрядной винды 7?

Tags: python-3.x

Сегодня я решил начать изучение языка Python. Я зашел на официальный сайт, но к сожалению не смог найти Пайтон 3.7.2 версии для 64-разрядной винды 7. Что мне делать?

Comment: не совсем понятно, как связано ***изучение*** языка с ***установкой***, так-то это разные вещи

Comment: Плохо у вас как-то с поисковой деятельность. [Прямая ссылка](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.2/python-3.7.2-amd64.exe).

Comment: Нашел за 10 секунд: https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/

Comment: Герман, вам для обучения должно быть достаточно версии 3.6, так как изменений там не особо много и пока вы до них дойдёте - уже поймёте какие тонкости между версиями. Так что вы главное начинайте, а остальное со временем придёт.

Comment: Можно начать учить английский, чтобы находить то, что лежит на видном месте.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что Stack Overflow не база ссылок для скачивания

Comment: это проще дня!!!

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю как вы обыскивали весь сайт, там все на виду. Откройте [эту страницу](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-372/) и прокрутите вниз. Вам нужны файлы, начинающиеся с `Windows x86-64`, например `Windows x86-64 executable installer`.

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что на этом сайте вы сможете найти любую интересующую вас версию:
https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/.
Так же советую скачать интерпритатор, для более удобной работы: 
https://www.wingware.com/downloads/wing-personal

Answer (score 1):

На [Официальном сайте Python](https://www.python.org/downloads) есть версии для `Win x86-64`, т. е. и для Windows 7.

**Оффтоп**
Всё же, лучше переходить со старых версий Windows, т. к. большое количество софта уже отказываются от них.